# put sprites hidden on screen,than fade them in

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to put some `CCsprites` on screen that later on will be fade in to screen.
I cant hide them ,because the `CCFade` action will not work on hidden sprite , or a sprite with `opacity=0` .

What i do is put them on screen and fade them out :

```
[colors[i] runAction:[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0]];
[self addChild:colors[i] z:0];
```

it turned out that fading out in zero time is `not unseen`, so they appear for a second the moment i add them to `CCScene.`

How would i put them on screen to be unseen, and than fade them in with `CCFadeIn` action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stack actions using a sequence. See the example below from one of my projects :

```
CCSprite *frame1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[frames objectAtIndex:0]];
frame1.flipX = self.flipX;
frame1.scale = self.scaling;
frame1.visible = NO;
frame1.opacity = 255;
frame1.rotation = self.rotation;
frame1.position = self.offset;
animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:(duration / self.numberOfFrames)];
id stall = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:delay];
id show = [CCShow action];
id animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
id hide = [CCHide action];
id clean = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    [frame1 removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

}];
id enchiladas = [CCSequence actions:stall, show, animate, hide, clean, nil];

[node addChild:frame1 z:5];
[frame1 runAction:enchiladas];
```

Similar thing. I want to run an animation that will appear after a set delay time, then vanish and cleanup after itself when complete.

Answer (score 0):

YOU can use sprite.opacity =0; initially
and in actions you can increase the opacity

Comment: Use [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:1.25f opacity:255] to fade from current opacity to full opacity in 1.25 seconds (for example).